# One data filter for many tables

Tags: filter

*I have two tables with columns:*

```
Table1.date.month
Table1.value


Table2.date.month
Table2.value
```

How can I create **ONE** data filter (like a list box), which will affect both tables?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union SQL statement to unite data from both tables in one select or view.

Example:

```
select [date], value from Table1
  union all 
select [date], value from Table2
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c910/1) for MS SQL Server 2012

You could use any front-end to display your data where and filter the united data, as an example, in you [AngularJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) web page with listbox for month filtering and showing the result of filtering